# Count the occurrences of two values in a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I want to count the occurrence of two values in a tensor. The following code works except for the case when one or both values are not present in the tensor. In that case it crashes with the (expected) error: `InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin and size arguments to be 1-D tensors of size 1, but got shapes [0] and [1] instead.`

How can I modify this code (without using a conditional) so it just gives a 0 count for the missing value instead of crashing.

```
wts = tf.Variable([[-2.0, 0.0, 0.05], [-0.95, 0.0, -0.05], [1.0, -2.5, 1.0]])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def count_occurrences(t, val1, val2):
    y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.reshape(t, [-1]))
    idx_val1 = tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.equal(y, val1)), [-1])
    idx_val2 = tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.equal(y, val2)), [-1])
    return tf.slice(count, idx_val1, [1]) + tf.slice(count, idx_val2, [1])

print(count_occurrences(wts, 1.0, -2.0).eval(session=sess))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that simply as:

```
wts = tf.Variable([[-2.0, 0.0, 0.05], [-0.95, 0.0, -0.05], [1.0, -2.5, 1.0]])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def count_occurrences(t, val1, val2):
    eq = tf.logical_or(tf.equal(t, val1), tf.equal(t, val2))
    return tf.count_nonzero(eq)

print(count_occurrences(wts, 1.0, -2.0).eval(session=sess))
```

Note however that, in general, [comparing floating point numbers for equality is not the best option](https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/floating-point-equality-its-worse-than-you-think/). A possible alternative with some tolerance could be:

```
wts = tf.Variable([[-2.0, 0.0, 0.05], [-0.95, 0.0, -0.05], [1.0, -2.5, 1.0]])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def count_occurrences(t, val1, val2, epsilon=1e-8):
    eq1 = tf.abs(t - val1) < epsilon
    eq2 = tf.abs(t - val2) < epsilon
    eq = tf.logical_or(eq1, eq2)
    return tf.count_nonzero(eq)

print(count_occurrences(wts, 1.0, -2.0).eval(session=sess))
```

Comment: Thanks. All successful comparisons will be with integers stored as float32. Therefore, there should not be any tolerance issues. The suggested solution works well with 0 counts and also is a bit faster than the original solution. Can you please suggest ways of speeding it up further?

Comment: @ahk3 They are pretty basic and fast operations, I'm not sure you can get much faster. If you are going to repeat the operation a lot over the same data and you don't have many possible values you could consider precalculating, or more advanced stuff like indices (I don't think there's anything like that already implemented in TensorFlow), but that's about it.

Comment: @ahk3 Actually I have updated it to us [`tf.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/count_nonzero), which might be a tad faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
wts = tf.Variable([[-2.0, 0.0, 0.05], [-0.95, 0.0, -0.05], [1.0, -2.5, 1.0]])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def count_occurrences(t, val1, val2):
    y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.reshape(t, [-1]))
    idx_val1 = tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.equal(y, val1)), [-1])
    idx_val2 = tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.equal(y, val2)), [-1])
    temp = tf.cond(tf.greater(tf.shape(idx_val1)[0], 0), 
               lambda: tf.slice(count, idx_val1, [1]), 
               lambda: [0]) 
    temp = temp + tf.cond(tf.greater(tf.shape(idx_val2)[0], 0), 
                 lambda: tf.slice(count, idx_val2, [1]), 
                 lambda: [0])
    return temp

print(count_occurrences(wts, 1.0, -2.0).eval(session=sess))
```