# Is there a tensor eqiv to python's list.count()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to do all my input pipeline work in tensorflow. This includes transforming the examples into the types required by the classifier.

I just learned I can't iterate over a string tensor like I would do with a standard python list. My specific question is "is there a tf function for testing the existence of a constant value within a tensor?" Of course there may be a better way to do this (I'm new to tf and python).

```
# creating a unique list of tokens (python)
a_global = []
a = [...]
for token in a:
    if a_global.count(token) == 0:
        a_global.append(token)
```

I'm indexing string tokens so I can essentially convert them into integers using the token's position within the list as its new value. That snippet will not work  when "a" is a tensor, so I'm trying tf.map_fn() instead, but I don't know how to replicate the IF statement predicate. Can someone point me in the right direction?

tf ver 1.8

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need gradients for this operation (which I guess you don't for preprocessing stuff), the easiest could be to use [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func). It essentially is able to wrap numpy code snippets into TensorFlow ops.

If that doesn't work for you, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331277/count-the-occurrences-of-two-values-in-a-tensor) to count occurrences. Then you could use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to replicate the if statement.

Comment: This is what I have at the moment: `ax = tf.map_fn(lambda f: tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.constant(idx_a.count(f)), zero), lambda: fn_true(f), fn_false), a)` where "zero" is a constant tensor. It doesn't seem to be working because when I start a session to print out the values in "ax" I just get empty strings: `(array([b'', b'', b''], dtype=object)`

Comment: Could you post a runnable example?